# Voice Action Activity

Tags: android, xamarin.android, intentfilter

Although I'm using Xamarin, I believe this to be a general Android development question. I'm developing an app, let's say "My App," that I'd like to be launched via the launcher and via voice using "Ok Google, start My App."

What I'd like to accomplish is to start MainActivity or VoiceActivity depending on the mode in which my app is launched. I found this blog post https://blog.xamarin.com/add-a-conversation-to-your-android-app-with-voice-interactions/ by James Montemagno but whenever I activate My App via "OK Google" it always starts at MainActivity.

I'm hoping someone can provide pointers on what intent-filters to add in order to accomplish this. Here's what I have so far:

```
<activity android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="My App" android:name="md593b8d625023f6802361dd1b8a6546be5.MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:label="My App" android:name="md593b8d625023f6802361dd1b8a6546be5.VoiceActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.VOICE" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I've also read older documentation/reports of apps needing to be made publicly available in the Google Play store to be indexed before "Ok Google" works correctly, but it's not clear if those are for custom actions or something as simple as launching an app via voice.

Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide, I've been banging my head trying to figure out what should be seemingly very easy...

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: did you found a solution to this?